# Share iOS application code without private keys

Tags: ios, xcode, oauth-2.0

It is possible to configure my local Xcode to include private keys injected into the application when compiling?

I'd like to share the source code in my repository with few people but I'm worried about my private keys for authenticating to remote services (OAuth2, etc.)

Currently I have #define them in source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always create a tiny static library on your local machine (and keep the source code for it on your local machine) which has the private keys (either unencrypted or scrambled inside them) and then include that static .a file in your source code repository.